# javascript inserting wrong apostrophe

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I'm using spring to return de simple string:

```
[['09:41',5,2.63],['09:49',6,2.63]]
```

My java script shoud use this string to populate a google line chart:

```
data.addRows([['09:41',5,2.63],['09:49',6,2.63]]);
```

The piece of code above works properly however when I try to replace the harded code by a variable, a simple a apostrophe appears out of the blue.

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
        var test = [[${chartValues}]];
        data.addRows(test);
/*]]>*/
```

The problem is when I printout in eclipse console this `chartValues` value, it shows properly:

```
[['09:41',5,2.63],['09:49',6,2.63]]
```

When I try to save this result in a variable `test` and so pass to `addRows` function as a thymeleaf argument, the result is:

```
data.addRows('[[\'09:41\',5,2.63]]');
```

I have no idea why this apostrophe is between `(` and `[`

My java class that build this string:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import br.com.carboni.utils.FileHandle;


public class BuildCsv {

    public static String buildArray() throws Exception {

        String path = Configuracao.path_monitora_disco;
        String currentDate = DateFormat.FormatDate();
        String filename = currentDate + Configuracao.filename;


        ArrayList<String> chartValues = FileHandle.readFileAsListOfStrings(path, filename);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                                                 

        for (String s : chartValues) {

            String hr = s.split(";")[0];
            String qtFiles = s.split(";")[1];
            String totalSize = s.split(";")[2].replaceAll(",", "."); 

            sb.append("['");
            sb.append(hr);
            sb.append("',");
            sb.append(qtFiles);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(totalSize);
            sb.append("],");

        }

        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I could solve the problem. In fact all I needed was to receive a string and convert it to an javascript array object.

I used @Scott Sauyet advice to use eval.

So I changed my controller to send a string like that `['string1', int2, int3],['string1', int2, int3]`.

In my javascript all I needed to do:

```
 /*<![CDATA[*/  
    var arr= eval("[" + [[${chartValues}]] + "]");
 /*]]>*/
```

and so:

`data.addRows(arr);`

Comment: Because it's treating your array as a `string`!

Comment: To change that String to an array, use `eval` (rarely recommended) or `JSON.parse`.  That latter will require you to first do `.replace(/'/g, '"')`, since it uses the wrong quotation mark for JSON.

Comment: But it's needed to be string. Otherwise javascript would not recognize it. The argument inside `addRows´ function must be string, as far as I know. I've tried return a stringbuilder object and it also didn't work.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thx for you advice to use eval.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a mistake in

```
var data = [[${chartValues}]];
data.addRows(data);
```

It looks like the **data variable is being used twice**.

Nevertheless, try this out:

```
data.addRows([[${chartValues}]]);
```

Cheers

Comment: sorry. typo mistake. In fact var data is var test.

Comment: `${chartValues}`  won't work once thymeleaf do not understand that syntax. It must be like that: `[[${chartValues}]]`. [Official documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)